# Angular2 use `listen` method from `Renderer` class to bind keyboard event like `keydown`

Tags: angular, keyboard-events

In my scenario, I want to bind `keydown` event to dynamically created elements.

So I use `listen` from `Renderer` class to implement it.

Here's my code snippet:

```
this.listenFunc = renderer.listen(elementRef.nativeElement, 'keydown', (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  console.log('Keypressed on element');
});
```

Unfortunately, it can't work, I can bind mouse event like `click` and `dblclick`, but unlucky with a keyboard event.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here a [Plunkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gcfIAlBoyirsJRotLe71?p=preview) for your refer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For keyboard events to work, an element needs to have the focus, for an element that is not an input element to be able to get the focus, it needs to have a `tabindex` set

```
 <h2 tabindex="0">Hello World!</h2>
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EaSR84MeiSI7tAfO6dcl?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond, `body` tag doesn't have `tabindex`, it can work if I bind keyboard event with `listenGlobal` like this 
` this.globalListenFunc = renderer.listenGlobal('body', 'keydown', (event) => {
      console.log(event);
      console.log('Document clicked');
    });
`,
So I'm still a little confused.

Comment: You can also set `tabindex` on `App` using `@HostBinding('tabindex') tabindex = 0;` and you can also listen to keyboard events using `@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])  onKeyDown(e) { ... }`. Your example should work as well.

Comment: Thanks Zoechi, it's a great idea, works well for me.